# Usage of "more" with countable nouns

Tags: grammar

Can anyone please tell me if expectation a countable or an uncountable noun in the following context? Because I think ***more*** is followed by plural countable nouns.

- He had more expectation of his sister Matilda grieving for him, even though her previous admiration had been tainted and diminished in recent months.

I found the above sentence sentence on the Internet. Shouldn't the word "expectation" have been in plural.

- We all have more expectation of death than of life.

This my own sentence. Is this correct?

- My father had no more expectation of hearing that I was alive ; but he received my letter a few days before he left London.

Does "no more" means "anymore" in the above context? I mean does it mean "My father did not had any expectation anymore of hearing that I was alive......"

- Adriana had no more expectation than Joshua did that her brother would allow Miranda to escape his protection.

I found this on the internet. I don't understand the meaning. Shouldn't the word "expectation " have been plural in the above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You can "more" with both countable and uncountable nouns:

> I want more rice.
>
> I want more chips.

Expectation is an abstract noun, and is uncountable in your example, which does not have a grammatical error.

"He had no more expectation" simply means he did not have more expectation. That is not the same as "anymore". In the second it is used to mean that Adriana has "less than or equal" amount of expectation, compared to Joshua.